# Custom UICollectionViewLayout with self-sizing Cells

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, autolayout, uicollectionviewlayout

I created a custom collection view layout and want to enable self-sizing cells. In general everything works as expected. Only the animation during a batch update makes some problems.

If I insert an item via a batch update, the collection view creates the cell correctly and asks the cell for the preferred layout attributes based on the estimated layout attributes from my layout. Then I check in the layout, if the size of the cell (the preferred attributes) has changed and invalidate the item with that index path.

The problem is, that the collection view continues to use the original layout attributes to animated the cell and applies the preferred attributes after the animation has finished. The result in the end is correct, but the animation in between is not so nice.

I created a small [sample project](https://github.com/anagromataf/SelfSizingCellsTest), that shows the problem and you can see the result in this [video](https://vimeo.com/115073015).

Comment: It looks like this is a problem in UICollectionView. During my "research" I found other having similar problems.